# Getting blank file trying to Import data with Beautifulsoup into csv

Tags: csv, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv, python-3.7

Don't know what is going on. It was working perfectly with the other codes importing to csv file. But somehow in this one doesn't pass the data. It creates the file but is blank.

If anyone could give a tip would be appreciated. Quite possible that is just a simple solution because I'm a newbie.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re
import csv
filename = "test.csv"
f = open(filename, "a")
headers = "location, country, type, level, deep, vision, water, 
access, life kind \n"
f.write(headers)
my_url = "http://www.example.com"
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
links = page_soup.select('sea > a[href]')
link = [tag.get('href') for tag in links]
for url in link:
    Client = uReq(url)
    pageHtml = Client.read()
    Client.close()  
    pSoup = soup(pageHtml, "html.parser")
    linkeas = pSoup.findAll(href=re.compile(my_url))
    def linkas(href):
        return href and re.compile("html").search(href) and re.compile(my_url).search(href)
    linka = pSoup.findAll(href=linkas)
    if linka != []:
        linkia = [tag.get('href') for tag in linka]
        for curl in linkia:
            cClient = uReq(curl)
            pageHtml = cClient.read()
            cClient.close() 
            Soup = soup(pageHtml, "html.parser")
            info = Soup.select('.val')
            if info != None:
                location = Soup.select('.last')
                if location[0].string != 'Page 2':
                    country = Soup.select('.cru > a:nth-of-type(3)')
                    countri = country[0].text.strip()
                    print(countri)
                    locat = location[0].text.strip()
                    print(locat)
                    tipo = info[0].text.strip()
                    print(tipo)
                    expe = info[1].text.strip()
                    print(expe)
                    depth = info[2].text.strip()
                    print(depth)
                    avg = info[3].text.strip()
                    print(avg)
                    cur = info[4].text.strip()
                    print(tipo)
                    acc = info[5].text.strip()
                    print(acc)
                    life = info[6].text.strip()
                    print(life) 
                    f.write(locat.replace(",", " |") + "," + countri.replace(",", " |") + ","  + tipo.replace(",", " |") + "," + expe.replace(",", " |") + "," + depth.replace(",", " |") + "," + avg.replace(",", " |") + "," + cur.replace(",", " |") + "," + acc.replace(",", " |") + "," + life.replace(",", " |") + "\n")
                    continue
                else:
                    continue
```

Comment: Is `links = page_soup.select('sea > a[href]')` or `link = [tag.get('href') for tag in links]` returning an empty list. If so, it never go into your `for` loop to write anything to the file.

Comment: Oh, hi again chitown. Yes sometimes links are empty. Is that a problem? Can't continue and write the ones with data? One the loop is showing all the rint ones...

Comment: ya if your `link` list is an empty list, there's nothing to loop through at `for url in link:`